# jQuery stop action "breaks" animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
function play_fu() {
   $( "#main_photo img" ).fadeOut(250, function() {
      //change photo with new photo ++
    }).fadeIn(-250, play_fu).delay(400); 
}

$( "#play" ).click(function() {
   $(this).hide();
   $( "#pause" ).show();

   play_fu();
});


$( "#pause" ).click(function() {
   $( "#main_photo img" ).stop(true);
   $(this).hide();
   $( "#play" ).show();
});
```

As you can see because of function `play_fu`, `#main_photo img` is always animated (something is added into its animation queue). When I click `pause` I want the last animation to take place, so to change photo with new photo, then `fadeIn` and then stop.

Now, what happens is that a new photo could not have yet faded in and the animation will immediately stop while clicking `pause`. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
$( "#main_photo img" ).stop(false, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ... it doesn't seem to stop at all the animation now when I press `pause`. It just keeps going.

Comment: oh. try with $( "#main_photo img" ).stop(true, true);. If still not working out, please set up a fiddle so that I can help you out further.